# Is "kindly" considered inappropriate to use?

Tags: culture

I'm from South East Asia, and in here, it's very common to use "kindly" as a written polite request to other people, and I often see it on the internet as well. But I've just discovered that from [this website](https://www.grammarly.com/answers/questions/8006-what-is-the-correct-way-to-write-pls-do-the-needful/), "kindly" is regarded as a *"low-brow, patronizing, and overly sensitive"*.

> Other people are recommending that you use the word "kindly". Please,
>   never use the word "kindly" when interacting with Americans. In the
>   view of Americans, only English-speaking Indians use this word. It
>   comes across as low-brow, patronizing, and overly sensitive.

Oh wow, I never know that. But coming from a non native western background and culture, I have nobody here I can crosscheck information with. Maybe someone here with the appropriate culture background knowledge can give some insight? Is this a general view, or just a partial view of Americans about this word? Should I stop using this word from now on, or I just overly worried over nothing? Thanks.

Comment: I think that is just one person's opinion.  *Kindly* does come across as slightly formal and old-fashioned, but "low-brow, patronizing, and overly sensitive"?!?!  Overuse of *kindly* come across as a bit patronizing, maybe, but that's all.

Comment: I took a look at the link. I wouldn't regard that one commentator as authoritative. It's rare to hear requests beginning with *kindly* in the US. It's more common to use *please* in place of *kindly*, but I have heard it nonetheless. I certainly wouldn't call it inappropriate, and I don't use phrases such as *low-brow*, particularly in reference to one's dialect. What I find to be most inappropriate was that person's answer to the question. I think he came across as racist to be honest.

Comment: @Giambattista actually, we usually combine the word "please" and "kindly" altogether. "Please kindly check this document attached." or "Please kindly review the last meeting's notes." Is this appropriate? Or too redundant?

Comment: Well, it certainly shouldn't offend anyone. I will say that to me, saying *please kindly…* is a little over-the-top, and I'm not sure that I've heard it that way before. But that doesn't make it inappropriate.

Comment: @ChenLiYong - "Please kindly" sounds strange to this American English speaker.  They mean pretty much the same thing, so using both is redundant.

Comment: @ChenLiYong At the risk of overstating the case, the guy who wrote this "advice" is something of a fool. As for _patronizing_, Mr Davis himself sounds like an exemplar of that trait. Some of his advice makes sense, but this particular nugget is just plain stupid. Remember, the internet is **big**. Always seek many answers (as you have done here!) For me, "kindly" can sound a _little_ off-putting, and you won't hear it used here in the same way as it is frequently used in S. Asian English. Use "please" until you have some real conversations of your own, and you'll "get it" eventually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please keep in mind that the post you provided is the opinion of **one** person. I think it's going to be difficult to accurately assess how Americans view the word *kindly*. I'm American, I personally do not harbor the feelings expressed in that post. In fact, if someone used the word *kindly* in that fashion, I would find it particularly polite.

Of course, this is also the opinion of one person. But I can assure you that *please* is certainly more popular than *kindly*. I provide some cursory search data of American English. I searched "kindly" and "please". It's hard to gather the exact meanings, since they can change according to context. However, notice the top return is "please do".
[image]

Expanding further, we see that *please do* dominates *kindly do*, as an example, and appears to have the meaning we seek.

[image]

If you want to be safe (around Americans), you should use *please*. But I truly do not think you need to worry.

Comment: This is a great scientific answer! In here, we rarely use "please do", so I have a little difficulty to put it into words. "Please do check this document attached" sounds a little patronising to me. But maybe that's because I'm unfamiliar with the phrase. So I'll try and learn to internalise it. Btw, can I get the url of this website if I want to run queries about commonly used words?

Answer (score 3):

I think that one of the main problems is that English language learners learn "nice words" like "kindly" and "please". They then believe that just by putting them into a sentence, the sentence will become polite.

Example:

> [At a performance] **Kindly** sit down and be quiet. (sounds fairly patronizing)
>
> [Exiting an elevator] **Please** move out of my way. (please is used but the sentence doesn't sound polite at all)

Examples of what I consider polite without using "nice words":

> [At a performance] We appreciate everyone's cooperation in keeping the performance quiet and enjoyable for the whole audience.
>
> [Exiting an elevator] This is my floor.

In short, using words like "kindly" can seem patronizing depending on contents of the sentence and situational context.

Comment: Yeah I can see how this comes to play. It's all depends on the motive and context too. Asian people sometimes try to keep the conversation polite, but actually has a subdued hostile meaning. So this is actually on point.

Comment: As a native English speaker I can confirm kindly almost always comes across as patronising, unless it's clear that the speaker has limited English skills, in which case you get let off (to an extent). It's somewhat akin to "I don't want to be rude, but" - which is then followed by something intentionally rude. Best avoided

Answer (score 1):

I am a Scottish Woman and I find the word kindly, in a certain context during conversation, very irritating.  Wondering why I was so irritated by this I looked up the correct use and meaning of this word.  Its seems to be a rather old fashioned word not commonly in use in the UK today; certainly not in conversation.  We tend to speak of someone as kind or of showing kindness towards another.  During my search, I found that in conversation it was quoted as "being used to take the edge of what would otherwise be a command"!  Consider the common phrase "please kindly listen while I explain this; or kindly wait while I check this."

In my view please is asking while kindly, as already mentioned, is used to take the edge of a command.  An example being in written format: 'kindly pay your debt at your earliest convenience.' The use of both words together is contradictory.

While I have no issue with please, I do find the word kindly exceptionally irritating in the context of conversation.  I feel it also implies that someone is considered to be unkind or behaving in an impolite manner if the person making that statement deems it necessary to command this from the person they are talking to. Really when considering the expression in the written format, you wouldn't be asking someone to pay their debt if they were being polite or reasonable; if they had been you would need to request this.  So again in the context of conversation I would suggest that it is actually rude.  I would rather say "a person was kind",  and rather than say "they were a kindly person", I would say they "were" or "are a kind person".  Perhaps "kindly" is an old fashioned word and its mistranslation is why we hear it being used today.  And while "kindly" may not be a rude word, I find the context of use is very relevant.

I accept the general intent of many non English speaker's may not be to offend; but I certainly find it very offensive.  I also have an issue with being told what to do so now I fully understand why this word, when used in that context, really gets my back up!

Answer (score 0):

As an American, I consider the use of the word "kindly" as a southern idiom that comes across (to me) as a condescending order, one that makes me want to advise that person where he can go.  That attitude was developed from several years working with a southern boss who is now thankfully not among us anymore.  This is similar to the phrase, "well bless your heart" which often means something much different, such as "well aren't you are an idiot."